# Determine maximum distance using Earths Movers Distance

Tags: c++, image, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I'm trying to determine what is the maximum distance possible that could exist between any 2 histograms using the function [EMD](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#emd) in OpenCV.

The reason is that I need to normalize (scale them on a range [0,1] being 0 = the same histogram, 1 = the most different histogram possible) a bunch of distances computed from a set of histograms (all the same size).

So I want to find the maximum distance to divide all the distance-set by it to scale into the range.

How could I find the maximum distance possible between 2 equal-sized (assume N dimensions), histograms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your cost matrix look like?

The worst case scenario would be the one where the weights of both histograms are accumulated in two respective bins which are maximally distant from each other.  In this case the maximum distance would be the [maximum of your cost matrix](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/rubner-jcviu-00.pdf) (if both histograms have equal total weight).

Comment: I'm not using any cost matrix, my call looks like **cv::EMD(sig1, sig2, CV_DIST_L2)** being *sig1* and *sig2* the signatures as described on the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#emd). All other parameters are kept as default. When testing a single dimension, 256 bin, 8-bit each I've seen distances from ~0 to ~20.
In this case, would max be when bin1 = 255 on hist1 and bin256=255 on hist2 (all other bins = 0)?

Comment: Indeed.  I just tested and the distance in that case is 255, which is the L2 distance of the 0'th and 255'th bins.